# chef assign elastic ip to instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud, chef, amazon-elastic-ip, cookbook

I am using a custom bash script to spin up/down EC2 instances as needed. The script creates the instance similar to: `knife ec2 server create --config .chef/knife.rb` with a few other parameters.  It creates the instance fine but I want to be able to assign my elastic ip to the current active instance.

Short of sending the output to a text file, parsing the output for the IP and instance name, and then running `ec2-associate-address -i $instancename $ipaddress` is there a good way to do this programmatically?

I believe I'm over thinking this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look at the [Opscode "AWS" cookbook](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/aws) which contains a LWRP for attaching elastic IPs to AWS instances.

Answer (score 0):

Found two answers.  You can script your own setup using the Fog ruby gem:

```
gem install fog
```

Or follow the tutorial here with Perl:

http://www.krzywanski.net/archives/592